Smoke simulations and how to render them
I recently began a real time smoke simulation system, and I need some help with the rendering. I didnt know if to ask here or on the game development stack exchange, but I decided here as it is physics related.
Practically, Im reading an article about fluid dynamics and Im having trouble understanding how to implement them with code. Like for example, all the calculations for advection, velocity etc. need to be done on every single grid object? Also what color would I need to color them when drawing the final image? How would I know if they should be more or less transparent? As you can see, I'm pretty lost when going to rendering.
By the way, Im really sorry if this was the wrong stack exchange, I just thought that since this question regarded a operation based on physics.
My last question (and possibly the most physics related one): is there any steps I could skip for the sake of computing speed? Like is there any steps which do not go to impact the overall effect too much?
Edit
One more question!
When we talk about a grid, I dont really understand if I would have to compute for each particle (not every one, but a fixed number I decide) in the simulation or should I just have the simulation run on every object in a grid?
Like do I calculate advection, projection etc. on each particle, and as they move through time, I keep doing the calculations with the same particle at the new position, or do I just select a cell position and do calculations for the particles that pass inside of that cell?
Again, please inform me if this is the wrong place to ask this!!!

I need some help with the rendering. Implementation details of computational tasks are off-topic on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

All the calculations for advection, velocity etc. need to be done on every single grid object? Yes. Smoke swirls around in 3D.

This is a very broad request. It might be better to ask instead for resources on CFD (though this would closed as a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210301/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/791550/25301 & more loosely https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515629/25301)

A lot depends on your intended application – are you trying to make a video or a cool looking animation for art or video purposes? Trying to realistically model smoke behavior to help with fire safety? Actually model turbulent particle-laden flow scientifically?

I'm attempting to balance how it looks with how many calculations per a second I would need to do. Like I would like realistic smoke, but that probably wouldnt run every second

Regarding all the previous comments, this post is regarding how to simplify smoke simulations (and a couple of questions on them), so I really wouldnt need people to write or debug my code. :)

The standard Navier Stokes equations can render smoke very well. You just need to color the density at each location (the higher the density the whiter the smoke, 0 density is pure black).

Wow, thanks! This solves the color problem! Ill be sure to.get back to you on this!

The short answer is to use the NS equations. The longer answer involves a chapter or two of a textbook to describe how that's done.
